# CSS: Flex doesn't keep same height for divs in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I’m currently using `display: flex;` to display 3 tiles that adjusts and keeps the same height based on which tile has the most content in it.

The below HTML/CSS works in all browsers except IE11 & I can’t figure out why.

I tried adding `min-height: 100vh;` to my `richTextOne` class but that keeps the height of all the containers the same & also blows up the height so it’s not what I’m looking for.

`min-height: inherit;` to my `richTextOne` class makes the containers not all have the same equal height. The height in each tile div goes as far as how much content is in it.

Any help is gladly appreciated.

Thanks!

```css
.flex-box {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 345px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.tile {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 348px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-right: 61px;
}

.richTextOne {
  flex: 1 auto;
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-left: 24px;
  padding-right: 11px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Flex rules will automatically sync height of all div.tile boxes -->
<div class=“flex-box”>
  <!--/* Tile 1 */-->
  <div class=“tile”>
    <div class="richTextOne">
      <p>blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--/* Tile 2 */-->
  <div class=“tile”>
    <div class="richTextOne">
      <p>blah</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--/* Tile 3 */-->
  <div class=“tile”>
    <div class="richTextOne">
      <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm genuinely curious why you're targeting IE11?

Comment: @Dai Because my client want to.

Comment: Okay, so _why does your client want it_? If they just said-so without giving a good reason then you have a professional-ethical obligation to push-back and inform the client they're making ill-informed decisions about the work they want you to do: because otherwise (without a good reason, which I assume they don't have) it's just going to cost them money to have you waste time working-around bugs that no-one is going to experience.

Comment: @dai Lots of our oversees customers use IE11 so we have to support it for now.

Comment: Right, if you have usage-stats that show that, then that's fine (and carry on), I was just taken aback because on all of the web-properties I'm responsible for, usage of all versions of IE has been under 1% for most of the past 5 years now. Good luck!

Comment: @Dai I feel you. However I'm not going to fight it really.

Comment: @カメロン Solved it. On my flex-box div I needed to add align-items:stretch; problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my `flex-box` div I needed to add `align-items: stretch;` in order for the child divs to be equal height. Thanks All!

Answer (score 0):

Add `align-items: stretch;` to your flex parent.

```css
.flex-box {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 345px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.tile {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 348px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-right: 61px;
  height: 100%;
}

.richTextOne {
  flex: 1 auto;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-left: 24px;
  padding-right: 11px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Flex rules will automatically sync height of all div.tile boxes -->
<div class=“flex-box”>
  <!--/* Tile 1 */-->
  <div class=“tile”>
    <div class="richTextOne">
      <p>blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--/* Tile 2 */-->
  <div class=“tile”>
    <div class="richTextOne">
      <p>blah</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--/* Tile 3 */-->
  <div class=“tile”>
    <div class="richTextOne">
      <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. The content appears but not all the same height for some reason. Any other ideas?

Comment: @spidey677 Try adding it to `.richTextOne`

Comment: I also added it to ``.richTextOne`` and now it added more space to the smaller divs but it's still not equal to the div with the most content.  Not sure what's going on.

Comment: @spidey677 Give that a try - the recent edits should do the trick.

Comment: @spidey677 Did this not work either? To be honest,  I don't have IE on my system either, but I have experienced this bug with flex on IE in the past, and this solved it for me.

Comment: Negative my friend. I've been trying to also set things like height:auto or height:100% and no luck either.

Answer (score 0):

There is a raft of bugs in IE11 related to flex.

See https://caniuse.com/?search=flex

In particular what seems to be relevant to your code:

> In IE10 and IE11, containers with display: flex and flex-direction: column will not properly calculate their flexed childrens' sizes if the container has min-height but no explicit height property.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have internet explorer 11 on my system, but I noticed that you fixed the width of tiles etc so if the page is resized it'll go out-of-place.

Test my code below and see if it works on ie11

```
<style>

    *, *::after, *::before {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .flex-box {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 345px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    }

    .tile {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 33%;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        margin-left: 1px;
        margin-right: 61px;
        background-color: #e2e2e2;
    }
        .tile:last-child {
            margin-right: 0;
        }

    .richTextOne {  
        padding: 1rem;
        display: block;
    }

</style>
```

```
<!-- Flex rules will automatically sync height of all div.tile boxes -->
<div class="flex-box">
<!--/* Tile 1 */-->
<div class="tile">
  <div class="richTextOne">
    <p>blah blah blah</p>
  </div>
</div>

<!--/* Tile 2 */-->
<div class="tile">
  <div class="richTextOne">
    <p>blah</p>
  </div>
</div>

<!--/* Tile 3 */-->
<div class="tile">
  <div class="richTextOne">
    <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you have any questions, please don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean tiles in IE don't obey `min-height: 345px`? Except this, I don't find other issues in IE 11.

If you mean the `min-height` issue, you can refer to [this doc](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-3). The fix is add a flex column wrapper around the `flex-box`:

```css
.flex-box {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 345px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.tile {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 348px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-right: 61px;
}

.richTextOne {
  flex: 1 auto;
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-left: 24px;
  padding-right: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
  <div class="flex-box">
    <!--/* Tile 1 */-->
    <div class="tile">
      <div class="richTextOne">
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--/* Tile 2 */-->
    <div class="tile">
      <div class="richTextOne">
        <p>blah</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--/* Tile 3 */-->
    <div class="tile">
      <div class="richTextOne">
        <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Actually solved it this morning. I needed to add `` align-items: stretch;``. Problem Solved.